# "Invalid Callee" while using MLapp in C#

Tags: c#, matlab, com, com-interop, matlab-deployment

I'm having a strange issue while using the [MLApp.GetWorkspaceData](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getworkspacedata.html) function. I noticed that this functions works properly when I do the following:

```
matlab = new MLApp.MLAppClass();

object myObject;

matlab.GetWorkspaceData("myVariable", "base", out myObject);
```

But if I then try to use the same object as an output I get an "Invalid Callee" exception. In addition this also gives the same error:

```
matlab = new MLApp.MLAppClass();

object myObject = new object();

matlab.GetWorkspaceData("myVariable", "base", out myObject);
```

This is very troublesome because I need to get a large amount of data from Matlab to Visual Studio, and I cannot practically create 52K uninitialized variables and keep them around. Is there some way to "uninitialize" a variable? Is there some concept I'm missing here?

Comment: You can set `myObject = null;` and the garbage collector should do the rest at some point.

Comment: Wonko, that actuall seemed to work. But I still have no idea what the heck is going on. Why cant I assign to a "new" variable? Why must it be uninitialized?

Comment: As you are calling Mathlab over a COM wrapper it maybe has something to do with that on process cannot alter stuff of the other or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

As [@wonko79](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118710/invalid-calle-while-using-mlapp-in-c-sharp#comment31776934_21118710) explained in the comments, if you want to reuse the `out` variable, you should set it to `null` first.

Here is a tested example [calling MATLAB from C#](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-a-c-client.html):

```
using System;

namespace CSharp_matlab_com
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MLApp.MLAppClass matlab = new MLApp.MLAppClass();

        // create variables: a_0, a_1, ..., a_4
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            matlab.Execute(string.Format("a_{0} = rand(2);", k));
        }

        // retrieve variables from MATLAB and print their contents
        object a;
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            // current variable name
            string varname = string.Format("a_{0}", k);

            // get data array
            a = null;    // without this line, an exception is thrown!
            matlab.GetWorkspaceData(varname, "base", out a);

            // print contents
            var arr = (double[,]) a;
            Console.WriteLine("\nndims(a) = {0}, numel(a) = {1}", arr.Rank, arr.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++) {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}[{1},{2}] = {3}", varname, i, j, arr[i,j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The output:

```
ndims(a) = 2, numel(a) = 4
a_0[0,0] = 0.251806122472313
a_0[0,1] = 0.617090884393223
a_0[1,0] = 0.290440664276979
a_0[1,1] = 0.265280909810029

...

ndims(a) = 2, numel(a) = 4
a_4[0,0] = 0.425259320214135
a_4[0,1] = 0.16148474431175
a_4[1,0] = 0.312718886820616
a_4[1,1] = 0.178766186752368
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper for `GetWorkspaceData` method, like in the next example:

```
public object GetData(string name)
{
    object data;
    mlApp.GetWorkspaceData(name, "base", out data);

    return data;
}
```

Or, even more useful, a generic wrapper:

```
public T GetData<T>(string name)
{
    object data;
    mlApp.GetWorkspaceData(name, "base", out data);

    if (data == null)
        return default(T);

    if (data is T)
        return (T)data;
    else
        throw new InvalidCastException($"The variable '{name}', of type '{data.GetType().Name}' cannot be casted to type '{typeof(T).Name}'.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set the output object to `null`.

I found it [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/49300-invalid-callee-when-using-matlab-as-a-com-server#answer_360378).